# Open Source Web Mapping with OpenLayers & PostgreSQL

Tags: open-source, postgresql, openstreetmap

I am planning to develop a web map application software which will run via a browser and for that I want to use open source. I already have some knowledge of OpenLayers & PostgreSQL. I want to use web map application for Land Use planning.

For instance we have a location and we need to divide that among some owners. Our GIS consultant will get GIS related data and divide that location in different polygons with respect to various owners. I want to use that data and show on a dynamic map. Upon clicking on any of the polygon on that location it will show, in a popup window,  further information such as owner id, owner picture, and many more. Google Map Api is doing some kind of this job but its not free after some hits.

I hope i was able to describe my problem and please suggest me best software for fulfilling this task.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like OTISS (https://www.otiss.co.uk/w/). It's primarily for tree surveys but has a 'street furniture section' that might do for your needs. It used Open Street Maps as its base map.

It was several years ago, but I was in consultation with the developer about custom layers and data collection fields, so if the website doesn't yield results, you might try contacting him.

It also provides a service whereby your clients (or stakeholders or bosses or whoever) can log in and review the data.

I have no connection to OTISS, but I do know people that use it and my experiences with the developer were positive.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) as a wrapper for Open Street Maps data, coding in AngualrJs. It works great, is powerful, but simple, with good documentation.

> divide that location in different polygons with respect to various owners. I want to use that data and show on a dynamic map. Upon clicking on any of the polygon on that location it will show, in a popup window, further information such as owner id, owner picture, and many more.

[image: Yes] Check - I am doing all of that

Comment: Dear both, thank you so much for your feedback and recommendations. Do you have a working example/project other than the one on Leaflet website. So that I could have a better understanding?